# Android to JAVA SSL

Tags: java, android, ssl

i am a relative novice at Android and have had issues getting a simple SSL connection working to a java server.

I know the java server works as I tested it using the same keystore as the server and a java client.

The Android client does send something as the java server accepts a connection and displays a null value for a readline variable, and no error message.

I have my keystore, and truststore in bks format, and added to the res/raw folder.

Android Client:

```
 SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();

    KeyStore trustSt = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    InputStream trustStoreStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
    trustSt.load(trustStoreStream, "password".toCharArray());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustSt);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    InputStream keyStoreStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
    keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "password".toCharArray());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){Log.d("SSL", nsae.getMessage());}
    catch (KeyStoreException kse){Log.d("SSL", kse.getMessage());}
    catch (IOException ioe){Log.d("SSL", ioe.getMessage());}
    catch (CertificateException ce){Log.d("SSL", ce.getMessage());}
    catch (KeyManagementException kme){Log.d("SSL", kme.getMessage());}
    catch(AccessControlException ace){Log.d("SSL", ace.getMessage());}
    catch(UnrecoverableKeyException uke){Log.d("SSL", uke.getMessage());}

    try{
         //error catch
         String error = "test";

         sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
         s = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("192.168.2.101", port);

            outStream = s.getOutputStream();
            outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outStreamWriter);

            bufferedWriter.write(error + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.flush();          

              } //end try
              catch (UnknownHostException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
              catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

              finally{
                     if (s != null){
                     try {s.close();} 
                     catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                     }
                     }//end finally 
 }
```

I have specified a truststore but do not not how to initialise the truststore on the socket.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `"passowrd"` typo deliberate?

Comment: i change the passwords when i pasted...was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this line

```
sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

to use the [`SSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#SSLSocketFactory%28java.security.KeyStore%29) may solve your problem.

```
sslsocketfactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustSt);
```

Comment: that constructor is for org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory, there was something wrong with the syntax, might be because i am  trying to use a  javax.net.ssl TCP socket